# Set/Get DeliveryTag RabbitMQ on Publish

Tags: c#, .net-core, rabbitmq

Is it possible to set the delivery tag on the message that I publish in my publisher client code?  Is it possible to get the delivery tag for the message that I publish in my publisher client?

Here is my situation:

1) I am creating a job (job a) that creates many messages that might take a long time to process.  Multiple jobs can be running at one time.

2) I am using a single queue

3) I am using a single receiver

4) I want the ability to "delete" all messages for job a.

If I knew what the delivery tag is then I can just ack each of the message to "delete" just the ones I want from the queue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do the delivery tags related to the messages for job A?

Comment: You can set custom headers for the message and delete the messages which match the value.

Comment: @Lutz, my thought is that if I know the delivery tag for the message then I can just acknowledge that delivery tag at any time and the message will be dequeued.

Comment: @bumblebee how do you delete a message by custom header? In a single client/publisher (no receiver) if I set custom header values then publish messages, you are saying I can create a for loop immediately after to delete those messages I just created? How do you do that? That would absolutely do what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can set custom headers for every message in the following way:

Publisher:

```
byte[] messageBodyBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello, world!");
IBasicProperties props = model.CreateBasicProperties();
props.ContentType = "text/plain";
props.DeliveryMode = 2;
props.Headers = new Dictionary<string, object>();
props.Headers.Add("header",  value);
model.BasicPublish(exchangeName,
               routingKey, props,
               messageBodyBytes);
```

Reference: https://www.rabbitmq.com/dotnet-api-guide.html#publishing

At the consumer you have access to the `BasicProperties`.

Consumer:

```
public override void HandleBasicDeliver(string consumerTag, ulong deliveryTag, bool redelivered, string exchange, string routingKey, IBasicProperties properties, byte[] body)

        {

            header_value = // Read the value from the properites variable

            if (header_value matches) {
                // Reject or delete the message
                _channel.BasicReject(deliveryTag, false);
            }
            else {
                // Accept the message and do your processing
                _channel.BasicAck(deliveryTag, false);
            }

        }
```

Reference: https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/rabbitmq/csharp-read-messages-from-rabbitmq-queue

I am using `RabbitMQ` with `pika` which is a `python` client. I am not that fluent with `C#` or `.NET`, but I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the response, however this will not work in my situation.  This is something I can do if I have to, but it is not ideal in my case.  What you explained is exactly what I want to do (logically) except without a consumer/listener.  Let's say that a consumer does not exist, how do I do this?
My use case is this.  I have 10 messages.  5 belong to MyProcess1 and 5 belong to MyProcess2.  There is no guarantee of order.  There is no consumer.  I want to run MyDeleteMessageApplication to delete/ack all messages associated to MyProcess1 only.